# How to build combination function in java?

Tags: java, arrays, combinations, permutation

I am studying interview questions.

And, I am having a hard-time to understand combination function.

I would like to build the combination function.

for example, if input is `[1,2,3]`
then I have to generate `[1,2,3] , [1, 3, 2 ] , [2, 1 ,3 ] , [ 2, 3, 1] , [ 3, 1, 2 ] , [ 3, 2 ,1]`

However, it shouldn't accept cases which has shorter length than input value. (for example, `[1]` , `[3,2]`)

And, number of elements in the input can be changeable ( `[1,2,3,4]` ,`[1,2,3,4,5 ,6]` )

However, I am not really sure how to start to build this function.

Does anybody can give some idea or example ?

thanks

Comment: Wouldn't this be a `permutation` method instead of a `combination`?

Comment: @splungebob shoue i say "permutation" ? I am not really sure.. but each case should have same length. it doesn't accept [1] ,[2,3] .. etc cases..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been pointed out you seem to mean [permutation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) rather than [combination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination).

The first approach that comes into my head is a recursive one - but I'm not sure how efficient it will be - perhaps an interesting question to consider for your interview questions!

```
public class Permutations {

   // testing
   public static void main(String[] args){        
    permutations(new int[]{1,2,3});    
   }

   public static void permutations(int[] array){
     boolean[] chosen = new boolean[array.length];
     int[] output = new int[array.length];
     permutation_inner(array,chosen,output,0);
   }
   public static void permutation_inner(int[] array, boolean[] chosen, 
                                        int[] output, int depth){
     if(depth==array.length){
       System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(output));
       return;
     }
     for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        if(!chosen[i]){
           chosen[i]=true;
           output[depth]=array[i];
           permutation_inner(array,chosen,output,depth+1);
           chosen[i]=false;
        }
     }
   }

}
```

Comment: thanks selig. it is really helping me to understand interview questions. I will try to improve function :) thanks!!